# Can't change css when using click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small demo:

```
<div class="box_content_height">
    <strong>Height: </strong>
    <input type="text" name="height" id="height" value="300" />px
    <input type="submit" class="submit_advance" value="submit" />    
</div>
```

And javascript

```
$('.submit_advance').click(function() {
        var height_css = $('#height').val();
        $('ul.nav-scroll').css('max-height', height_css+'px');
});
```

When I type input = 500 is result css no change 500
How to result is

```
.ul.nav-scroll {
    max-height: valueofinput+px
}
```

Comment: max-height will only actually change the height of the DOM if the content exceeded that of the previous height.

Comment: It was working fine check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kGSbn/

Answer (score 1):

change this :

```
$('ul.nav-scroll').css('height', height_css+'px');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `submit` may be causing the page to reload due to the form being submitted, undoing your changes.  If you don't want this to happen, add a `return false` to the end of your handler.

Answer (score 0):

is this a typo? Your css definition has a "." in front of ul:

```
.ul.nav-scroll {     max-height: valueofinput+px }
```

your javascript selector does not correspond with the above:

```
$('ul.nav-scroll').css('max-height', height_css+'px');
```

Your css should be:

```
ul.nav-scroll {     max-height: valueofinput+px }
```